# HTML5 resizes divs to the right and not the left

Tags: html, css, transition

When I hover my mouse over the first picture, it expands and the other divs decrease, when you do it to any other div than the first one, it only alters the divs on the right and not the left.

You can find my code so far and see how it works so far.

```
<div id="slider">

<div id="allpic1">
 <img src="http://www.coolusbtoys.com/wp-content/Angry-Birds-space-Calendar-2013.jpg"/>
</div>
<div id="allpic2">
  <img src="http://i4.ytimg.com/sh/G2lfbxaIEy4/showposter.jpg?v=4fbb28d7"/>
</div>
<div id="allpic3">
  <img src="http://ec2.images-amazon.com/images/I/41hmD1hLmBL._SL500_AA300_.jpg"/>
</div>
<div id="allpic4">
  <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-55F_zXg6TKI/UKB6cCTZ1XI/AAAAAAAAB3c/um9nqYtzfY4/s1600/61bEcpAzU0L._SL500_AA300_.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS

check the link below

http://jsfiddle.net/dBGeV/

Comment: Just a follow on, I solved this problem by using jQuery to on click change the css, using fadeIn and fadeOut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you try to achieve is not currently possible with CSS alone, unless you find a completely different way of doing it.
Can't think of any, but I'm no CSS expert.

Anyway,
The `A ~ B` "general sibling selector" will select B if

- B is a sibling of A **and**
- B is located after A.

There is no way to select a sibling located *before* A.

So this works for your first div, but afterwards all the divs left of the "hovering" one are not selected.

Btw. your percentages should be adjusted if you want to occupy 100% of the width.
The expanded div takes up 80%; so the 3 remaining divs should take up 20/3 = 6.66%.
I would set the expanded div to 79% and the others to 7% to avoid floating point numbers.

Comment: Excellent response, thanks so much, adjusted my aspect of all of html5.